# SOQL on lookup field on standard object

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to get the related Case.Origin from MessagingSession, whenever I do the query on dev console or salesforce inspector, I can get the Case.Origin. However on my actual code it doesn't return any Case.Origin to my lwc

Here is my code:

Apex:

```
List<MessagingSession> messagingSessions = new List<MessagingSession>();
messagingSessions = [SELECT Id, Case.Origin, CaseId, Status, StartTime, EndTime
                                FROM MessagingSession 
                                ORDER BY StartTime DESC];  
return messagingSessions;
```

LWC:

```
for(c in response.messagingSessions){
  let o = response.messagingSessions[c];
  this.id = o.Id;
  this.origin = o.Case.Origin;
  this.caseId = o.CaseId;
  this.status = o.Status;
  this.startTime = o.StartTime;
  this.endTime = o.EndTime;
}
```

I am getting values on id, caseId, status, startTime & endTime however the origin is blank. But whenever I perform the query on dev console or salesforce inspector the Case.Origin has values

Comment: Have you attempted to log the messaging session record that you're receiving in the LWC? Or is that how you've determined that it is coming through as null?

Comment: Your query works for me in exec anon...have you shared all the relevant detail? Otherwise I'd be guessing it's a data or permission issue.